# What would this sentence be considered?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, sentence

"I wonder why X's don't have (insert subject) and you do" Is it a question? Statement? A question imbedded in a statement? Or would it depend on the tone that was used?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As it stands, it's not a sentence at all… are the underscores meant to be placeholders standing in for actual words? Like for example, “I wonder why I don't have any money and you do”?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Yes. My apologies. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

It's context sensitive.  If you are genuinely asking "I wonder why the other bakery doesn't have dinner rolls, but you do?", then it's just a question.

If you are not asking in order to get a response, but are instead commenting on the sad state of the other bakery (perhaps you are making a point to this baker that he needs to be well-stocked in dinner rolls,) then it's called a rhetorical question and may not require a question mark.

Comment: Yes; your first analysis is a hedged version of 'Why do you have dinner rolls while the other bakery doesn't?' It might be included in the set of 'declarative questions', but these normally require yes/no answers.  The second, the rhetorical version, is signalled by a different tone in speech, or a full stop rather than a question mark in print. But this grades into a declarative statement; 'wonder' (now = 'am intrigued') is a multi-purpose verb.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The reason I am asking is because someone I know told me that it is a statement, not a question, and in order for it to be a question it would have to be worded like this, "I wonder if X's have (insert subject) like you do".

Answer (score 0):

In the declarative sentence

> I wonder **why** the Joneses don't have a Lexus and you do.

the word "why" serves as a subordinating conjunction to introduce the clause

```
Joneses (subject)  --  don't have  (verb)  --  a Lexus (direct object)
```

The structure is the same as the related sentence

> I wonder **that** the Joneses don't have a Lexus and you do.

with the word "that" taking the place of "why."  The difference is in the meaning:  in the second sentence, you're contemplating the automotive disparity; in the first, the reason for the difference.

The clause in the first sentence isn't a question, but you may transpose it into one, using why as an interrogative adverb:

> Why don't the Joneses have a Lexus?

Notice the difference in the word order.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. The reason I am asking is because someone I know told me that it is a statement, not a question, and in order for it to be a question it would have to be worded like this, "I wonder if X's have (insert subject) like you do".

Comment: @Jennifer Nope, still a statement.

Comment: If it was said in a questioning tone would that make a difference? Like, would that make it a rhetorical question?